# How do you change an element in an integer array?

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I am having trouble changing the value of an element in an integer array.
I am getting the error Type'()'cannot conform to 'View'.

I am very frustrated. I can reference the specific element without any error!

```
Import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]
var body: some view {
  // no error

  Text(String(someInts[1]))
  // line below generates an error????

  someInts[1] = 16
}
```

Comment: You need to read the **very basics** of `SwiftUI`, see for example: [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/).
 You cannot add "normal" procedural swift code anywhere you like in a SwiftUI View body. You can add this type of code in special 
 places, such as `.onAppear {....}` or functions. Note also, you cannot change a value of a `var someInts:[Int] ...`, as 
 the **very basics** of `SwiftUI` tutorial will tell you, you need to have `@State var someInts:[Int] ....`.
 Without knowing the **very basics** of `SwiftUI` you will have a lot of these type of problems

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a `View`

Most swift views will be a (often chained) single expression, and so have an implicit `return` statement.  If you are including other expressions inside the `View` struct then you will need to explicitly return the view.

This implies you need to do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]
var body: some view {
  let textView = Text(String(someInts[1]))
  someInts[1] = 16
  return textView
}
```

However this still won't work as the struct is immutable. You need to persist any data outside of the `View` struct or use the `@State` (or other state-persisting) property wrapper to allow you to mutate it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]
```

While this will compile, it still makes little sense as you will display the text, then modify the underlying data, which will force the view to immediately update.  You might just as well initialise the array with the value and avoid the flicker!

Comment: I only showed the bare minimum of code because of what I am really trying to do would give away what I am going to eventually publish. I will test your answer tomorrow. Thank you!